# How Turing machines were built, from the hardware point of view, to read data? And erase?

Tags: history, turing-machines

My question is more on the engineering side; I would like to know how, physically, computation machines were built in the beginnings.
How Turing machines could read and erase? They wrote on a paper ribbon, but how physically did they read? Was there optic fiber in those times? And how could they erase? Were there any magnetic ribbons of some kind?
I just want to understand the genesis of it all.
Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: In general a Turing machine is a mathematical abstraction. There are better designs for real world problem solving. I'm not aware of any early computers that where exactly Turing machines, in the sense that they had tapes nothing else.

Comment: As PiRocks said, there aren't really any physical Turing Machines. A TM is meant to encapsulate the idea of what a human might do with a pencil and paper when doing a math problem. Maybe this will help: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33769/is-there-a-physical-analogy-to-the-turing-machine

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, you are encouraged to answer your own question.

Comment: Oh ok, I am new to this :-) Just transfered the answer at the right place, thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers, I understand better now :-) And also, I found videos on Turing machines that were actually built for representation purposes, here are the links, it is pretty interesting:

[The Only Working Turing Machine There Ever Was Probably | The Henry Ford's Innovation Nation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_Hj5x6OWTM)

[Mechanical Turing Machine in Wood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vo8izCKHiF0)

[Electronical Turing Machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivPv_kaYuwk)